# Slice behaving differently in Django development than when running under IIS

Tags: python, django, iis, django-templates

I am confused.  I have a list view which provides links to a detail view.  I wanted the detail view to be able to go back to the (calling) list view.  There were some reasons that an ordinary back button wouldn't do the trick; so I decided to provide the list view's url to the detail page by assigning request.path to a parameter named last_page.

If I am running in the Django development environment on port 8000, **last_page|slice:'1:'** removes the leading '/' from my variable.  When I run the same code under IIS (10), I have to use **last_page|slice:'0:'** to do the same thing or I get a NoReverseMatch error when I try to use last_page in my detail template.  I get this behavior in both environments on a Windows Server 2016 machine.  (Python 3.7.3, Django 2.2.5, wfastcgi 3.0).

In my list view template, my URL looks like this:

```
href="{% url 'a-detail' pk=s.s_id last_page=request.path %}"
```

In my detail template, the code I use for the back button looks like this (**This is where the slice removes the initial '/' from request.path**):

```
<script>
document.write('<a href="{% url last_page|slice:'1:' %}">Go Back</a>')
</script>
```

In my urls.py file, I am using these url paths (don't really need the one for not passing the parameter any more):

```
path('<int:pk>', views.ADetailView.as_view(), name='a-detail'),
path('<int:pk>/<path:last_page>', views.ADetailView.as_view(), name='a-detail'),
```

The views.py file for my detail page looks like this:

```
class ADetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
model = Base
template_name = 'a_detail.html'

# Handles form that changes status
def post(self, request, pk, last_page=2):
    obj = SChanges.objects.get(pk=pk)
    obj.status = SStatus.objects.get(status_id=request.POST.get('status'))
    obj.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('a-detail', kwargs={'pk': pk, 'last_page':last_page}))

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ADetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['last_page'] = self.kwargs.get('last_page')
    return context
```

I was expecting to have **|slice:** work the same in both environments.  Can someone explain why I have to use '1' in the Django development environment and '0' under IIS?

Thanks--

Al

Comment: Could you share what is your base URL in the Django environment and in iis? what is your folder structure and URL before and after hosting in iis? you could refer [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)

Comment: I am running the my app out of the same folder on my Windows Server 2016 for both Django and IIS.  The code is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app.  I just either run it as http://localhost:80 with IIS or http://localhost:8000 wth Django (running 'python manage.py runserver' in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\app).  I don't see why this would change the behavior of slice.  Thanks!